# PowerShell: System cannot find file when user not logged on

Tags: powershell, certificate, certificate-store

When I try to use `Import-PfxCertificate` I get an error when the user account I'm running the script with isn't logged on:

> Import-PfxCertificate : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

When I open an RDP session to the server the script runs at on that user account, it works without problems. The weird thing is that `Test-Path $certfile -PathType Leaf` returns true in both cases. What is going on?

```
Test-Path $certfile -PathType Leaf #always true
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certfile -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $Secure_String_Pwd
```

So the script is run as a background job on a timer on the server and when,

case 1: user account that is used to run the script has an active RDP session, the script runs fine.

case 2: user account that is used to run the script doesn't have an active RDP session, the script fails.

Edit: I found something in error[1].

```
New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Default\.Azure\AzInstallationChecks.json'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.profile\5.8.2\StartupScripts\AzureRmError.ps1:17 char:9
```

What's this then?

Comment: This may not be appropriate to your situation, but could you use a different certificate store: cert:\localMachine\my

Comment: This helped to get me along with the problem. So I changed the certificate store to LocalMachine and it required me to give the running user account administrator privileges, but now it works. The only thing is, that it only kicks the same problem further along the script and makes the problem even weirder. Now I get the same error with Connect-AzureRmAccount and it doesn't even use files!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your command on my console, and I had no issues with the import. I am an admin on the machine that contains my console. I tried this with the powerShell session being elevated and non-elevated. Both worked.

```
$certfile = "C:\temp\cert.pfx"
$secure_string_pwd = convertto-securestring -string "password" -asplaintext -force
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certfile -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $Secure_String_Pwd
```

If this is not helpful at all, I will just delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code and see it it works. Please post a complete exception if it doesn't work.

```js
try
{
$Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'DDDDD12345' -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath 'C:\LocalPath\local.pfx' -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $Secure_String_Pwd
$thumbprint =  (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\my| Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq "CN=certificateNameWithoutextension"}).Thumbprint

# code for connect-Azure RM account
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ApplicationId $appid -CertificateThumbprint $thumbprint -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal
}
catch
{
    Write-Output $_
    echo $_.Exception|format-list -force
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't help. The full exception is

> PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My
>
> Thumbprint                                Subject
>   ----------                                -------
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  CN=derp
>   Connect-AzureRmAccount : The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> At C:\temp\script.ps1:8 char:5
>   +     Connect-AzureRmAccount -ApplicationId $appid -CertificateThumbpri ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], Crypto 
>      graphicException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmA 
>      ccountCommand

Anyway, I went around the problem using C#.